# Can't compile a hello world in haskell

Tags: haskell, compilation

I just started to learn haskell using book "Get Programming with Haskell". The first think I am trying to do is simply compile hello world example from this book.
My code in file hello.hc is:

```
main = do
    printStrLn "Hello!"
```

I run ghc using command

```
ghc hello.hc
```

But all I got is an error!

```
hello.hc:1:1: error:
     warning: data definition has no type or storage class
     main = do
     ^

hello.hc:1:1: error:
     warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'main' [-Wimplicit-int]

hello.hc:1:8: error:
     error: expected expression before 'do'
     main = do
            ^
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)
```

My Haskell Platform version is 8.01,

Comment: According to the [relevant section of the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Introduction_to_Haskell_IO/Actions) it should be `putStrLn` and not `printStrLn`.

Comment: After changing the file ending, that's their next error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rename `hello.hc` to `hello.hs` and try

```
ghc hello.hs
```

again.

Calling

```
ghc --help
```

on my compiler explains (parts of usage omitted):

```
For each input file, the phase to START with is determined by the
file's suffix:

    - .lhs  literate Haskell         unlit
    - .hs   plain Haskell            ghc
    - .hc   C from the Haskell compiler  gcc
    - .c    C not from the Haskell compiler  gcc
    - .s    assembly language        as
    - other passed directly to the linker    ld

The phase at which to STOP processing is determined by a command-line
option:

    -E      stop after generating preprocessed, de-litted Haskell
             (used in conjunction with -cpp)
    -C      stop after generating C (.hc output)
    -S      stop after generating assembler (.s output)
    -c      stop after generating object files (.o output)
```

If you try to compile your `test.hc` with `gcc` that is just the error message you get from the `C` compiler.

```
[nix-shell:~]$ gcc -x c -std=c99 -o test test.hc
test.hc:1:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 main = do
 ^~~~
test.hc:1:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-int]
test.hc:1:8: error: expected expression before ‘do’
 main = do
        ^~
```